# Slider control in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, slider

what is the slider control called in .NET 4.0?

The one which lets you slide a marker and from one end to the other.

Like this:

[image: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/SliderTest.PNG]

Can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Controls.Slider (in WPF)
System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar (in WinForm)
```